# iOS push notifications are not sent with testflight

Tags: ios, push-notification, testflight

My iOS app sends push notifications which works great when installing the app from X-Code (with dev and production certificate) however, when installing the app from test flight, we are getting bad token response from Apple.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Our problem was with production flag disabled in the json file